# Showing that the following two norms are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\displaystyle ||x||_1=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$ and $\displaystyle ||x||_2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{|x_i|^2}\right)^{1/2}$. Show that the two norms are  equivalent.

From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality I found that $||x||_1\le \sqrt n.||x||_2$. But I am unable to find that $||x||_2 \le c||x||_1$.

Comment: Note that if $x = (1,1,1,\ldots)$, then
$$
\|x\|_1 = n \text{ while } \|x\|_2 = \sqrt{n}
$$
so your estimate is incorrect. Try the case where $n=2$ by drawing the unit balls in both these norms.

Comment: To add to my answer and to help you in the future, these kind of inequalities are often proved by squaring the norms. When I find myself stuck in such proofs, that often is the first thing I try. As you can see, squaring is really all there is to it, you are done in 1 line. So keep it in mind, it's a handy trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$||x||_2\leq||x||_1$ follows easily from inspecting $||x||_1^2$ and $||x||_2^2$:
$$||x||_2^2=|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+\ldots+|x_n|^2\leq\left(|x_1|+\ldots+|x_n|\right)^2=||x||_1^2.$$
The inequality follows from the fact that you are squaring the sum of non-negative terms. Now since norms are non-negative, $||x||_2^2\leq||x||_1^2$ implies $||x||_2\leq||x||_1$.

**Edit:**
As Prahlad Vaidyanathan said, your first bound is incorrect. By Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{|1\cdot x_i|}\right)^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^n{1^2}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n{|x_i|^2}=n\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}$$
So
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{|x_i|}\leq\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}} \iff ||x||_1\leq\sqrt{n}||x||_2.$$