# Prove that $d_u(x,y), d_{sum}(x,y)$ and $d_u(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are equivalent metrics.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that $d_{max}(x,y), d_{sum}(x,y)$ and $d_u(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent metrics,

where $d_{max}(x,y) = max\lbrace|x_i-y_i|:1 \leq i \leq n\rbrace, d_{sum}(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|$ and $d_u(x,y) =\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$.

Two metrics $d_1, d_2$ on a space $X$ are equivalent if there exist $a, b>0$ and $a<b$ such that $a \,  d_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y) \leq b\, d_1(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

I have already done the proof for $n=2$, but it was difficult for me to generalize the proof. Maybe you can help me?

Comment: Show $d_{\text{max}}(x,y) \leq d_u(x,y) \leq d_{\text{sum}}(x,y) \leq n\cdot d_{\text{max}}(x,y).$

Comment: Also, compare what you're written in the title with what you've written in the body text.  I think you have at least two typos.

Comment: The condition you wrote is Lipschitz equivalence, which is stronger than [ordinary equivalence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics).

Comment: This is certainly a FAQ. Let us find some duplicate.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547276) is one for "$d_{sum}$" equivalent to "$d_u$".

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = (x_1,\ldots x_n)$, and use the fact that

$$
\biggl(\operatorname{max}_{1\leq j\leq n}\vert x_j\vert\biggr)^2\leq \sum_{j=1}^n\vert x_j\vert^2\leq n^2 \biggl(\operatorname{max}_{1\leq j\leq n}\vert x_j\vert\biggr)^2
$$

We used $\biggl(\operatorname{max}_{1\leq j\leq n}\vert x_j\vert\biggr)^2=\operatorname{max}_{1\leq j\leq n}\vert x_j\vert^2$ for the first estimate. Taking square-roots finishes the proof.

Comment: This is certainly a FAQ. Better link to some duplicate than edit such an answer.